# webservice to detect if a website is up or down

Tags: web-services

I am looking for a webservice similar to www.isup.me which will return the status of a website in Json format.

Eg: http://www.isup.me/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [Pingdom's REST API](http://www.pingdom.com/services/api-documentation-rest/), which responds with JSON?